# Dialog loads on page before it disappears

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm using JQuery UI dialog that pops up when a user clicks a button (otherwise, it should be hidden). When the page loads, the dialog is actually seen on the page for a few seconds before disappearing (because the dialog is embedded onto the page). Is there anyway to prevent this appearance when loading?

Comment: That probably means that either the css or js that hides it initially is not loaded soon enough. It should be very simple to adjust that.

Comment: I figured as much, but how? Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that I have all my .js files at the bottom of the webpage?

Comment: While sloppy, you could go right on the element itself and and put `style="display:none;"`. There should be a better way, though. Inline style is bad practice. It might even have a bad side effect.

Comment: or you can "hard code" and place a css on top to make that particular id/class/element = display:none;

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. I tried the display:none method and it worked. I also tried moving all my javascript files to the top of the page and it worked as well (they were at the bottom before). Which method is superior? I'm assuming the former because it allows all the html to load before having all the js load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you set Dialog box html , set this dialog box css

```
{display:none}
```

or if you want by jQuery then  onpageload apply

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dialgboxid").hide();
});
```

now if you load page then this problem not appear 
and when you open dialog box by click it appear correctly